# Accessing class's properties after using List<>

Tags: c#, list, class, object, inheritance

I'm a beginner in C# and I have a particular question that is related in inheritance and polymorphism based on using classes. The assignment that I'm working is a bank account and that I have to use three classes-one is a base class while the other two are derived classes. 
The base class is known as "BankAccount" and the two derived classes are"CheckingAccount" and "SavingsAccount". Furthermore,  I have declared objects for "CheckingAccount" and "SavingAccount" and that they are stored in a List class. Afterwards, I'm trying to populate my assignment's GUI's labels accordingly based from the derived class's properties by using a combobox's "SelectedIndexChange" event. 
The problem is that somehow the program doesn't check if the list class's stored elements are recognized as a particular type. Below of this contains my code for the program and the classes.

```
 private void comboBoxAccountNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,  EventArgs e)
    {

        if (selectedBankAccount[0] is CheckingAccount)
        {
            labelOwnerID.Text = selectedBankAccount[0].AccountNumber;
            labelBalance.Text = selectedBankAccount[0].Balance.ToString("c");

        }

        else if (selectedBankAccount[1] is CheckingAccount)
        {
            labelOwnerID.Text = selectedBankAccount[1].AccountNumber;
            labelBalance.Text = selectedBankAccount[1].Balance.ToString("c");

        }


    }

     List<BankAccount> selectedBankAccount = new List<BankAccount> ();

    SavingsAccount savs1_Account;
    CheckingAccount chek1_Account;
    SavingsAccount savs2_Account;
    CheckingAccount chek2_Account;


    private void FormBankOfYourSelf_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        savs1_Account = new SavingsAccount("0001", "31-1000", 100m, 0.01);
        chek1_Account = new CheckingAccount("0001", "44-1000", 250m, true);
        savs2_Account = new SavingsAccount("0002", "31-1001", 1000m, 0.0125);
        chek2_Account = new CheckingAccount("0002", "44-1001", 500m, false);  
        selectedBankAccount.Add(chek1_Account);
        selectedBankAccount.Add(chek2_Account);

        comboBoxAccountNumber.Items.Add(selectedBankAccount[0].AccountNumber);
        comboBoxAccountNumber.Items.Add(selectedBankAccount[1].AccountNumber);


    }
```

```
 public abstract class BankAccount
{
    // Fields - The data we want to store
    // Naming convention for fields is to use underscore before the name
    protected string  _customerId;
    protected string  _accountNumber;
    protected decimal _balance;

    //Properties - Allow access to fields (Get/Set)
    // Get = read access
    // Set = write (modify) access
    public string CustomerId
    {
        get { return _customerId; }
        set { _customerId = value; }
    }

    public string AccountNumber
    {
        get { return _accountNumber; }
        set { _accountNumber = value; }
    }

    public decimal Balance
    {
        get { return _balance; }
    }

    // Methods - The action or behaviors the class can do
    // almost always, define the constructor and ToString methods
    // Constructor creates (instantiates a new object)
    public BankAccount(string customerId, string accountNumber, decimal initialBalance)
    {
        //fields are set = to the parameters(inputs from the form)
        _customerId = customerId;
        _accountNumber = accountNumber;
        _balance = initialBalance;
   }

    public abstract bool Deposit(decimal depositAmount);
    //{
    //    // If the depositAmount is less then 0 then RETURN false
    //    if (depositAmount <= 0)
    //    {
    //        return false;
    //    }

    //    // Otherwise, complete the deposit and RETURN true
    //    _balance += depositAmount;
    //    return true;
    //}

    public abstract bool Withdraw(decimal withdrawAmount);
    //{
    //    // If the withdrawAmount is greater than the balance or less then or equal to 0 
    //    // then RETURN false (don't allow withdrawal)
    //    if (withdrawAmount > _balance || withdrawAmount <= 0)
    //    {
    //        return false;
    //    }

    //    // Otherwise, complete the withdrawal and return true
    //    _balance -= withdrawAmount;
    //    return true;
    //}


   public class CheckingAccount : BankAccount
   {
    //private string _customerID;
    //private string _accountNum;
    //private decimal _initBalance;
    private bool _overdraftProtection;

    public CheckingAccount(string customerId, string accountNum, decimal initialBalance, bool overDraft)
        :base(customerId, accountNum, initialBalance)
    {
        //_customerID = customerId;
        //_accountNum = accountNum;
        //_initBalance = initialBalance;
        _overdraftProtection = overDraft;
    }

    public bool OverDraftProtection
    {
        get { return _overdraftProtection; }

        set { _overdraftProtection = value; }
    }

    public override bool Deposit(decimal depositAmount)
    {
        if(depositAmount > 0)
        {
            _balance += depositAmount;
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool Withdraw(decimal withdrawAmount)
    {
        if(withdrawAmount <= _balance || withdrawAmount > 0 )
        {
            _balance -= withdrawAmount;
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }




}
```

**Update: I noticed that when I run my program, even though I select different items within the combobox, it doesn't change the values to a selected item accordingly. Below is my program running with different items being selected. 
[First selected item in combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOQ0V.jpg) 
[Second selected item in combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd3Tb.jpg)

Comment: If you're only using properties of the base class (`AccountNumber` and `Balance`), why do you care what the derived class is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is of type `BankAccount` so you need to cast the object to the specific inherited class you want to work with before the properties will become available

Using the `is` keyword and then the `as` keyword is expensive performance wise because you are basically casting twice.  Best to use the `as` keyword and test for null

```
CheckingAccount account = selectedBankAccount[0] as CheckingAccount
if(account != null)
{
    //account is of type CheckingAccount so the additional 
    //CheckingAccount properties should be available via the account variable
}
```

Comment: I see. Hmm... I tried something like that to cast the list class's element into the intended inherited class, however, it doesn't work. I noticed that when I run my program, even though I select different items within the combobox, it doesn't change the values to a selected item accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

From posted comments it turns out the problem is that the code is not selecting the `BankAccount` selected in the ComboBox.  Not knowing how the ComboBox is populated.  The easiest way is to use the selected index assuming comboBoxAccountNumber is populated with the selectedBankAccount collection.

```
private void comboBoxAccountNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,  EventArgs e)
{
    BackAccount account = selectedBankAccount[comboBoxAccountNumber.SelectedIndex]

    labelOwnerID.Text = account.AccountNumber;
    labelBalance.Text = account.Balance.ToString("c");
}
```

Comment: Yes, that actually makes sense. Hours ago, I figured out the issue that the program doesn't read the code which indicates that it doesn't know the items in the combobox. Thank you so much for your help. I  have done a different method in considering your method.